# Unable to save the form data with the validation fire in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am adding dynamic fields of different names.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Selected Field</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sfNameSecC" placeholder="Enter field name" />
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 6px;">@@</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" style="padding: 6px;" name="sfPercentageSecC" />
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 6px;">%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 6px;">on</span>
            <select class="form-control" name="sfDropdownSecC">
                <option>Select field</option>
            </select>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success addButtonSecC1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="sdHdnSectionC" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And for the dynamic fields:

```
 <!-- The template for adding new field -->
<div class="form-group hide" id="selectedSecCTemplate">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sfNameSecC" placeholder="Enter field name" />
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 6px;">@@</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" style="padding: 6px;" name="sfPercentageSecC" />
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 6px;">%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 6px;">on</span>
            <select class="form-control" name="sfDropdownSecC">
                <option>Select field</option>
            </select>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success removeButtonSecC1"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the validation, i am using jQuery as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedField1Validators = {
        validators: {
            notEmpty: {
                message: 'Field Name is required'
            }
        }
    },
selectedField2Validators = {
    validators: {
        notEmpty: {
            message: '% is required'
        },

    }
},
selectedField3Validators = {
    validators: {
        notEmpty: {
            message: 'Mapping Field is required'
        }
    }
},
selectedFieldIndex = 0;


// Add button click handler for Section C - Selected Fields
            .on('click', '.addButtonSecC1', function () {
                selectedFieldIndex++;
                var $template = $('#selectedSecCTemplate'),
                    $clone = $template
                                    .clone()
                                    .removeClass('hide')
                                    .removeAttr('id')
                                    .attr('data-sf', selectedFieldIndex)
                                    .insertBefore($template);

                // Update the name attributes
                $clone
                    .find('[name="sfNameSecC"]').attr('name', 'sfNameSecC').end()
                    .find('[name="SfPercentageSecC"]').attr('name', 'sfPercentageSecC').end()
                    .find('[name="SfDropdownSecC"]').attr('name', 'sfdDropdownSecC').end();

                // Add new fields
                // Note that we also pass the validator rules for new field as the third parameter
                $('#frmAddPackage')
                    .formValidation('addField', 'sfNameSecC', selectedField1Validators)
                    .formValidation('addField', 'SfPercentageSecC', selectedField2Validators)
                    .formValidation('addField', 'SfDropdownSecC', selectedField3Validators);
            })

         // Remove button click handler for Section C - Selected Fields
        .on('click', '.removeButtonSecC1', function () {
            var $row = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
                index = $row.attr('data-sf');

            // Remove fields
            $('#frmAddPackage')
                .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="sfNameSecC"]'))
                .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="sfPercentageSecC"]'))
                .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="SfDropdownSecC"]'));

            // Remove element containing the fields
            $row.remove();
        })



 .on('added.field.fv', function (e, data) {
if (data.field === 'sfNameSecC') {
                if ($('#frmAddPackage').find(':visible[name="sfNameSecC"]').length >= MAX_NUMBER) {

                    $('#frmAddPackage').find('.addButtonSecC1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        })

.on('removed.field.fv', function (e, data) {
if (data.field === 'sfNameSecC') {
                if ($('#frmAddPackage').find(':visible[name="sfNameSecC"]').length <= MAX_NUMBER) {
                    $('#frmAddPackage').find('.addButtonSecC1').removeAttr('disabled');

                }
            }
        })
```

Here i am able to get dynamic fields. But when I miss one filed input and click submit button the validation is fired. After clearing the validation the submit button is firing an error message like "Unable to get property 'find' of undefined or null reference". When i comment the validation:

```
    var selectedField1Validators = {
        validators: {
            // notEmpty: {
            //     message: 'Field Name is required'
            // }
        }
    },
```

The submit button works fine. Here i am attaching the images please have a look.

Validation fire on missing field value:
[image: validation fire on missing field value]

After entering the field value this is the error i am getting on submit button click:
[image: after entering the field value this is the error i am getting on submit button click]
Please help me with another solution.

Comment: Can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: please post more of your jQuery/JavaScript... we do not have enough information.

Comment: @Clayton i have included all the jquery code that i am using ... please have a look.. thank you